# Memory leak in tornado generator engine with try/finally block when connections are closed

Tags: python, memory-leaks, generator, tornado, try-finally

This awesome code, shows memory leak in tornado's `gen` module, when connections are closed without reading the response:

```
import gc
from tornado import web, ioloop, gen

class MainHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    @web.asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        gc.collect()
        print len(gc.garbage)  # print zombie objects count
        self.a = '*' * 500000000  # ~500MB data
        CHUNK_COUNT = 100
        try:
            for i in xrange(CHUNK_COUNT):
                self.write('*' * 10000)  # write ~10KB of data
                yield gen.Task(self.flush)  # wait for reciever to recieve
            print 'finished'
        finally:
            print 'finally'

application = web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

application.listen(8888)
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

and now, run a simple test client, multiple times

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8888/')  # exit without reading response
```

Now, server output shows, incremental memory usage:

```
0
WARNING:root:Write error on 8: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
1
WARNING:root:Read error on 8: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
WARNING:root:error on read
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 361, in _handle_read
    if self._read_to_buffer() == 0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 428, in _read_to_buffer
    chunk = self._read_from_socket()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 409, in _read_from_socket
    chunk = self.socket.recv(self.read_chunk_size)
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
2
ERROR:root:Uncaught exception GET / (127.0.0.1)
HTTPRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:8888', method='GET', uri='/', version='HTTP/1.0', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', body='', headers={'Host': '127.0.0.1:8888', 'User-Agent': 'Python-urllib/1.17'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1021, in _stack_context_handle_exception
    raise_exc_info((type, value, traceback))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1139, in wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/gen.py", line 120, in wrapper
    runner.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/gen.py", line 345, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(next)
  File "test.py", line 10, in get
    self.a = '*' * 500000000
MemoryError
ERROR:root:500 GET / (127.0.0.1) 3.91ms
```

If you set `CHUNK_COUNT` to 1, the 10KB of data can be written to OS connection buffer, and 'finished' and 'finally' texts will be printed to console, and because generator is completed, no memory leak occurs.

**But the strange part** is that if your remove the try/finally block, the problem disappears!! (even with `CHUNK_COUNT` set to 100)

Is this a bug on CPython or tornado or ...?!

Comment: what version of tornado are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug tested with Tornado 2.4.1 (the latest version when this question asked), and reported on https://github.com/facebook/tornado/issues/660 .

The problem fixed in commit https://github.com/facebook/tornado/commit/769bc52e11656788782a6e7a922ef646503f9ab0 and included in Tornado 3.0.